# What do tower controllers do when the airport is quiet?

Tags: air-traffic-control

Listening [Hayward Executive](https://www.airnav.com/airport/KHWD) Tower on LiveATC in the night, I noticed ATC can be quiet for periods of more than 30 minutes, and sometimes the communication is not even with an aircraft, but with a maintenance car.

What do ATC operators when the airport is quiet?

Comment: I used to fly a lot of night freight back in the late 1980s and the 1990s, both in the U.S. and in Europe. While I can't answer your question, I can tell you that tower controllers always answered me promptly in the middle of the night (if the tower was shown as operating) when there was no other traffic but us. There was one exception; Valencia, Spain, where we would often land without clearance after repeated attempts to contact the tower.

Comment: Center controllers will happily "name that tune" or look up trivia to settle bets during dead hours, too.  It may be non-standard, but at least it keeps the pilots and ATC awake.

Comment: [They monitor 121.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_emergency_frequency)

Comment: Sometimes they take a nap. http://www.nbcwashington.com/news/local/Air-Traffic-Supervisor-Accused-of-Sleeping-in-the-Tower-118548444.html

Comment: When I used to fly at night and there was nobody else in the pattern they'd rate my landings.

Comment: I've heard that 123.45 can be a fun place to tune if you are flying and bored. Just make sure to only put it one one radio so you can be on either guard or atc if you are called.

Answer (score 2):

The same things people do when working jobs like night shift guard shack operator... catch up on paperwork, read, study, listen to music, etc.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to this claim?

Comment: LOL! Sure, hanging out with my controller friends in the Marines. :) Do you have a reference to disprove it?

Comment: Listening to music with speakers is frowned upon in the cockpit, and by the same principal it should extent to controllers too. I'm not sure how that applies to military operators though.

Comment: "Listening to music with speakers is frowned upon in the cockpit..." Ah, no, sorry, it isn't. Simple proof of that is that most modern intercom systems, either panel-mount or stand-alone, have connections for external audio and/or things like iPods, and features like auto-mute when there is audio coming from a source like a VHF radio. Dynon and PS Engineering are just two examples of manufacturers that do that.

Comment: that's why I said "with speakers". The auto-mute function is specially designed for the use in cockpit. Question is, do controllers have equivalent audio equipment?

Comment: Speakers and headphones make no difference. Audio is audio. Auto-mute is available in both panel mount and standalone versions with speaker and headset outputs. The same technology is available to anyone, not just pilots and controllers. How long have you worked in avionics?

Comment: 100% Agree with your answer. And I have done all of them at some point, including doing the Exams I am studying for and writing new procedures for the tower I am in. Music is allowed in a lot of towers, it is in the local instructions for some towers or in the case in the local ANSPs regulations or operations manuals. Speaker is safer then headphones in a tower as most towers don't use full headsets all the time. Some towers have a commercial radio going all the time.